# javac's recognition of packages

Tags: java, powershell, compiler-errors, package, javac

I have a package *LMath* with a class *LMatrix*. *LMatrix* has a method *public LMatrix getInverse()* that throws *LDimensionException*. 
The first line in both of these files is:

```
package com.kavricious.LMath;
```

Compiling this class in jGrasp results in no problem, but if I enter

```
PS C:\programming\java\javaprojects\com\kavricious\lmath> javac LMatrix.java
```

in Windows PowerShell, the stack trace reads:

```
LMatrix.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
   public LMatrix getInverse() throws LDimensionException{
                                      ^
   symbol:   class LDimensionException
   location: class LMatrix
```

how do I tell javac to recognize members as in the same package?

Comment: Packages are folders.  Do `LMatrix` and `LDimensionException` live in separate folders?

Comment: What directory are you in when you type that command-line? What is the directory structure of your project? In other words, what directories contain your .java files?

Comment: Also, what are the package declarations at the top of each file?

Comment: If LDimensionException is in the same package, then it will be recognized. If not, then you'll need to either fully qualify its package, or add an import statement. Same will apply if the LDimensionException class is in a separate jar, but you'll have to add it to the classpath when you attempt to compile, if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\programming\java\javaprojects\com\kavricious\lmath> javac LMatrix.java
```

That should be

```
C:\programming\java\javaprojects> javac com\kavricious\LMath\LMatrix.java
```

And similarly for all other Java files: compile from the root of the package hierarchy, and name the entire path to the .java file. Then the object files will be put in the right place, and found, and the ither .java files will be compiled as necessary.